# Javascript RobotJS colorAt function only working on one window

Tags: javascript, robotjs

I have a JavaScript script that uses robotJS to find the color of pixels on the screen. I have created a test function that uses the current position of the mouse to read the color of pixels and display them to the console as hexadecimal. It seemed to work at first. It was displaying different colors of gray. Since I am using VS Code, the color scheme of it is mostly different shades of gray. Then I placed my mouse over the color blue it displayed a gray result. As I kept testing different colors I found that it seemed to only display the colors of the window I entered the command on.

Here is the test function:

```
function findCurrentMouseColor(img) {
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        let mouseX = robot.getMousePos().x
        let mouseY = robot.getMousePos().y
        let mouse_color = img.colorAt(mouseX, mouseY)
        console.log("Mouse color: " + mouse_color)
    }
}
```

Here is my main function

```
function main() {
    sleep(5000) //gives me time to move to a different window where there are multiple different colors other than gray

    let img = robot.screen.capture(0, 0, 1920, 1080)

    findCurrentMouseColor(img)
}
```

Here are my results:

```
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c4c4c4
Mouse color: c4c4c4
Mouse color: c4c4c4
Mouse color: c4c4c4
Mouse color: c4c4c4
Mouse color: c4c4c4
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cccac2
Mouse color: cccac2
Mouse color: c1b885
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: c1b04f
Mouse color: d7c458
Mouse color: d7c458
Mouse color: d7c458
Mouse color: ffe869
Mouse color: ffe869
Mouse color: ffe869
Mouse color: ffe869
Mouse color: f2dd63
Mouse color: f2dd63
Mouse color: f2dd63
Mouse color: f2dd63
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: cac5ad
Mouse color: cac5ad
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c9c4a5
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: bfae4e
Mouse color: ffe869
Mouse color: cccbc7
Mouse color: cccbc7
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cbcbcb
Mouse color: cbcbcb
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cacaca
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c8c8c8
Mouse color: c8c8c8
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: c9c9c9
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: cccccc
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: c7c7c7
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
Mouse color: cdcdcd
```

Why is this happening, and what steps should I take to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

`robot.js` has some trouble with for loops, or rather I should say that javascript has some trouble with `robot.js`. I would recommend using `setInterval()` for outputting data:

```
const robot = require("robotjs")

setInterval(() => {
    mouse = robot.getMousePos()
    let color = robot.getPixelColor(mouse.x, mouse.y)
    console.log(color)
}, 100)
```